# Vagrant Windows Box takes forever to start after 'vagrant up'

Tags: windows, vagrant

I am on a Mac OS X Mavericks trying to run a Vagrant Windows 7 box (http://aka.ms/vagrant-win7-ie11).

Also I have installed the vagrant-windows plugin and have configured the Vagrantfile with the following properties:
PS: Don't consider the syntax below. It's just to represent what is configured in my file.

```rb
gui = true
memory = 2048
cpu = 2
```

So when I run the 'vagrant up' command I get this output:

```
gyo-macbook:Win7 gyo$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'win7'...
```

it takes forever and I don't see any progress nor any changes in the VirtualBox related vm folder.

Is there any steps I have forgotten?

Thank you,

Gyo

Comment: Doing this for the first time right now and it took 25 mins. Good post. Will “vagrant up” be faster next time aroundv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vagrant downloads the box the first time you `vagrant up`. After downloading it unpacks the box and imports it into VirtualBox. Windows boxes are fairly large 5+ GB, so expect the first vagrant up to take time to complete.

If you open the VirtualBox GUI while vagrant is doing it's thing, you will see when the box gets added to VirtualBox. You can also see if the box is booting up in the little preview window in VirtualBox.